# How can I sudo as a different user inside a script

Tags: unix, sudo

Currently I am logged in unix server using userid "bob". But i want to sudo as different user(masteruser) inside a script.

My current code is

echo password | sudo -S masteruser bash

In above line password is my password and masteruser is the user which i want to connect.
But executing that line i am getting error "sudo: masteruser : command not found"

Can you please help me out for the same.

Comment: Are you running the script interactively?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo password | su masteruser -c "echo this is the command you wish to run as masteruser"
```

Comment: I tried this command:   echo password | su masteruser -c nohup sh -x /tmp/cron.sh > /tmp/cron.log  2>&1 & . It created file cron.log having owner as bob, which is wrong. It shuld be created by owner masteruser. Also in the cron.log file there was error su: invalid option -- 'x'. Try `su --help' for more information.